# Session data is losing with Flash

Tags: php, flash, session, codeigniter, uploadify

I'm using Flash uploader(uploadify, swfupload) with CodeIgniter, want to get the session data. I have found out that the flash does not send the session data, so I have set `$config['sess_match_useragent']   = FALSE;`

Now for example i have set session value `myname` in session and I can get it on my backend PHP script using **Internet Explorer**. :

```
Array
(
    [session_id] => f4l82aa3f82rd4b2ed682e0e132d7a72
    [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1
    [user_agent] => Shockwave Flash
    [last_activity] => 1310546544
    [myname] => test
)
```

But the problem is that it works fine **ONLY** on **Internet Explorer**. On Internet Explorer, the `session_id` remains same before and after using flash.
But on the Firefox and all other browsers, the `session_id` is Changed and I can get only session_id, ip_address, user_agent, last_activity **BUT** not `myname`.

```
Array
(
    [session_id] => c2cafff6daadc5148e6646s8c4c2aafa
    [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1
    [user_agent] => Shockwave Flash
    [last_activity] => 1310548338
)
```

By browsing and asking the previous questions on SO, I found out that since the Flash deletes the session data, I should send the current Session ID to the backend script and then restore the session using that session ID. So I am setting the session_id using original session ID.

```
$original_session_id = $_REQUEST['session_id'];
$newdata = array(
            'session_id'  => $original_session_id,                   
               );
    $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

Now I can see that the session ID is set successully and it is same as previous, but the problem is that I still can not get the other session data, such as `myname`. Why is that so? Shouldnt I get it because now my `session_id` is same. Where does the session data goes and how can I retrieve it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reopen the session using `session_id()` as follows...

```
session_id($original_session_id);
session_start();

$this->session->set_userdata($_SESSION);
```

Comment: doesnt work. `var_dump($_SESSION)` will return NULL even there's `session_start();` before it.

Comment: you can't have a `session_start()` before the code in my answer, the `session_id()` call has to be before the `session_start()`

Comment: Jaitsu The `$original_session_id` gets the session id successfully but i am not sure if the next line (`session_id($original_session_id);`) is working or not  How can i check if this line is working? In standard php it works fine but not in codeigniter.

Comment: after the `session_start()` a var_dump($_SESSION) should return all session data for that session_id (not just the session_id)