# Session data is visible; is it ok?

Tags: php, security, session

Can the user view data saved in session? For example, if a user log-in to a website, and his `user_id` is saved in session, so that the user stays logged in as long as his id is available in the session. Can he view the session data? If he can view, is it bad?
Sorry if my question sounds stupid, but I have a problem which I'm trying to solve for whole day:

I'm using a flash uploader, when i send the data to another page, the flash uploader loses the data and i am unable to get the data from session, as i asked in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676758/session-data-is-losing-with-flash). Since sending `session_id` is not solving my problem, im thinking to pass the `user_id` which is stored in session along with the other data, and when the back-end script gets the `user_id`, it stores it in the session again so that the user stays logged in. 
For example, i can send the `user_id` with javascript (uploadify syntax):

```
'scriptData'     : {'uid': '<?=$this->session->userdata('uid')?>'},
```

and on back-end script i can get the `user_id` by:

```
$uid = $_REQUEST['sid'];
var_dump($uid);
```

Now since I am sending the `user_id` with javascript to the back-end script, the user can very easily see that his `user_id` is being passed. I have a doubt if its very insecure? Can the user somehow change the user id and send it (and log in as another user?) Is it possible?

The other possible way is to pass the session_id instead of user id (Which I am unable to do it yet), is sending `session_id` makes more secure than sending `user_id`?

Comment: The problem here isn't seeing the user ID, it's being able to change it.

Comment: Security is relative and always depends which level you need to achieve. As long as data is read-only for example, it's not always unsafe to reveal information. On the other hand, if knowing a user-id allows creating new users or to access existing accounts, you'll have a problem. For your case, do not develop something new on your own but understand an existing mechanism better and use code that is proven working and sound. And do not try to make something secure that just isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never send `user_id`. That would be a huge security hole in your app, as users will be able to change it to hack into other users account.

You should send the  `session_id`, and then do this on the server side:

```
<?php session_id($_GET['session_id']); ?>
```

This will start that session.

And yes, storing data in sessions is secure.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

Answer (score 1):

If your user_id is in any way predictable, then yes, the user could view and change their user_id, which will make your website think it is a different user. They may then have access to the information of the user they are impersonating.

This is potentially a significant breach of user security.

Answer (score 0):

No they can't view the data stored in a session.

A session ID only refers to the session data on the server, so data stored in the session is safe if you pass the session_id.

Note you should not expose the user_id as it offers an opportunity to change it.